# Detect if an UpdatePanel is affected by an Update() method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I use several UpdatePanel in the same page, with `UpdateMode = Conditional`, and i'm trying to find a clean way to only execute code behind related to the UpdatePanel which will be updated.

So, when i'm calling a `__doPostBack` from JS, i am able, on the code behind side, to detect the name of the UpdatePanel which is asked to refresh by using `Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` (which gives me the `ClientID` of the UpdatePanel).

But when i'm calling the `UpdatePanel1.Update()` method (from server side), is there a built-in way to know if an Update panel is about to be updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting here *to myself* my temporary (?) answer.

Because there is *apparently* no way to detect if a UpdatePanel is being updated (when UpdatePanel is updated by code behind), i've created a class which handle the update, and put some data in session, so, this same class will be able to tell if the UpdatePanel is updating.
So, I doesn't call anymore directly `UpdatePanel.Update()`, but `UpdatePanelManager.RegisterToUpdate()`.

The method `bool isUpdating()` is able to tell if an UpdatePanel is updating, and can tell automatically if an updatePanel is Updating though Javascript using `HttpContext.Current.Request["__EVENTTARGET"]`.

Note: `isUpdating()` need to be used within the `OnPreRender` Page event.

```
public static class UpdatePanelManager
{

    private const string SessionName = "UpdatePanelRefresh";

    public static void RegisterToUpdate(System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel updatePanel)
    {
        updatePanel.Update();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName] = new List<string>();
        }
        ((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName]).Add(updatePanel.ClientID);

    }

    public static bool IsUpdating(System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel updatePanel)
    {
        bool output = false;

        // check if there is a JavaScript update request
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == updatePanel.ClientID)
            output = true;

        // check if there is a code behind update request
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName] != null
            && ((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName]).Contains(updatePanel.ClientID))
        {
            output = true;
            ((List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionName]).Remove(updatePanel.ClientID);
        }

        return output;

    }

    public static bool IsUpdatingOrPageLoading(System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel updatePanel, System.Web.UI.Page page)
    {
        bool output = false;

        if (!page.IsPostBack || IsUpdating(updatePanel))
            output = true;

        return output;

    }


}
```